# GoogleMaps Overlay (floatPane) does not recive Click events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What do I need to configure to receive Click-Events in GoogleMaps Overlays?

I have set up a minimal Js-Fiddle Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EsbEL/4/

I inherit my own class from `google.maps.OverlayView` which creates a DIV and attaches it to the maps floatPane.

In the example above i clone a DIV from the same site - Click Events work on the template but not in the Overlay-Div... Any Ideas?

Here is an other example I found on the net which shows jQueryUI as an Overlay: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5KVY6/302/
And this controls recive Clicks just as normal... and I dont find the difference.

EDIT:
Sofar i have found that GMaps creates the overlay asynchronous, so my click handler for the link didnt get attached, it works with `$(..).live`, but I am still not able to click a button or enter text into a textbox; I have updated my example above.

Thx,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the click event to the copied content. Adding this code where getPanes() is just works

```
...
var panes = this.getPanes();  // yet exists
// example
$(this._div).click(function(){alert('here I am');});
```

Comment: Thx, with your hint I found, that GMaps creates the Overlay asynchrony - but still no clicks on buttons/inputboxes; see edit above